# sql merge statement for many columns

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, excel

I am currently developing a program in C# that takes a giant excel sheet(~14,300 rows, 90 columns) and needs to insert it into a database (SQL server 2014). The user can search through the DB for different products and eventually make a quotation for the customer.

To insert I am successfully using SQLBulkcopy to insert the excel rows into a staging table. The issue is, I want to use a merge statement to merge my staging table and real table as there maybe multiple uploads of the same file with very slight changes over time. All sql merge examples I'm finding look something like this:

```html
MERGE INTO maintable as Target
USING stagingtable as Source
ON Target.columnA = Source.columnA
WHEN MATCHED THEN 
UPDATE SET Target.Name = Source.Name
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
INSERT (columnA, Name)
VALUES (Source.columnA, source.Name)
```

The statement would work but the issue is, my excel file has 90 columns. Is there a way to update the whole row at a time or do I have to update each of the 90 columns of a row ?

Comment: You should probably ask a different question for your p.s., I think you'd have better luck getting answers. You can link to this question so you don't have to type the description over again

Comment: yeh i realised after posting. My first post, usually just a lurker.

Comment: You can update/insert into as many columns as you want, you can only match on 2 conditions but remember, the purpose of this is "does this record exist? if yes update if no insert", you are not trying to determine if a row that already exists has changed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to list all 90 columns one by one, there's no update the whole row. Go to SSMS, select the table, right click, script table as -> update to, and that'll give you the list of all columns in a script you can modify or copy/paste to your merge script.

Answer (score 0):

The merge transaction will only update what you tell it to, and generally only a row at a time. It will hinge off the merge targets (you can declare multiple). I would say it *always* does one row at a time, but that is a bolder statement than I am willing to make as it may be wrong.

If the row already exists (ie the merge targets match) then you only need to update the columns you want (you don't need to do each one), if they don't match then you have to do the whole row for the insert.

Is this answering your question or am I missing what question is?

Edit: I think an SSIS package would be better suited for this just fyi :)

Comment: the excel sheet is a large price list that has info about products and services offered. so a random column can change like, 'the lab the product is serviced in'. it is important that he whole row updates since i am not going to know which column will be changed by the user.

Comment: That column has to have some sort of unique identifier to it, that is what you target on, then assign the column values accordingly. Again though, I think an SSIS package would be nicer, you can BCP into that temp table you mentioned, and then use the SSIS package to merge all the data together.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `MERGE` statement to write to multiple columns. It uses basically the same syntax here that other DML uses:

```
....
UPDATE SET A = a, B = b, ...
...
```

Similarly for inserts.

Answer (score 0):

```
ALTER proc [dbo].[MST_Employee_Insert_Update]
  @XMLSTR xml = '<DocumentElement><VM_MST_Employee><ID>1</ID></VM_MST_Employee></DocumentElement>',
  @OUTPARAM int = 0 out
AS
BEGIN
 SET @OUTPARAM = 0;
 SELECT 
 x.value('ID[1]','int') as ID,
 INTO #MST_Employee
 from @XMLSTR.nodes('/DocumentElement/VM_MST_Employee') as xtbl(x)

        SELECT * FROM #MST_Employee

        MERGE MST_Employee As TARGET
        USING #MST_Employee  AS SOURCE ON TARGET.ID = SOURCE.id
        WHEN MATCHED THEN
      UPDATE SET 
      TARGET.FirstName =  SOURCE.FirstName,

      WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
      INSERT (FirstName) VALUES( FirstName );

            if @@ERROR = 0
            BEGIN
            SET @OUTPARAM = 1;
            END
            ELSE
            BEGIN
            SET @OUTPARAM = 0;
            END
END
```

Comment: Hi mayurgnu, and welcome to SO!  Generally speaking, code-only answers are discouraged on this site.  Would you be willing to edit your answer to include an English explanation of how and why your code solves the problem?  Thanks!